# Функция input() TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
print( sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0) )
```

Почему когда я хочу, чтобы данные вводил пользователь, то программа перестает работать:

```
numbers = list( input('') )
print( sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0) )
```

Выскакивает ошибка: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Как мы должны угадать, что Вы ввели?

Comment: Числа же
Например : 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо понимать, что делает `numbers = list( input('') )`. Для наглядности заменим `input('')` на `"1,2,3,4,5"`
Строка `numbers = list("1,2,3,4,5")` эквивалентна коду:

```py
numbers = []
for element in "1,2,3,4,5":
    numbers.append(element)
```

---

### Что значит `for element in "1,2,3,4,5"`?

Это значит перебрать каждый **символ** из строки `"1,2,3,4,5"`. А что такое символ? Правильно, это строка длины `1`. Таким образом строка

```py
numbers = list("1,2,3,4,5")
```

Вернёт **список**, элементами которого будут **символы** (запятые тоже!!), т.е. строки длины `1`
Далее Вы пытаетесь просуммировать все **символы** строки, удовлетворяющие какому-то условию. И условие выглядит `if символ % 2...`. Как Вы себе представляете взятие остатка от деления **строки** на **число**? Думаю, доходчиво объяснил, в чём у Вас ошибка.

---

Чтобы исправить, очевидно, надо, чтобы не было взятия остатка от деления символа на число. Как? Зависит от формата вводимых данных. Если цифры вводятся через запятую, то:

```py
numbers = input()
numbers = numbers.split(",")  # Разделяем строку по запятым
numbers = [int(number) for number in numbers]  # Преобразовываем каждую строку-число в число-число
```

И далее уже работаете с `numbers` как со списком **чисел**.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
numbers = list( input('') )
# 12345

print( sum(int(x) for x in numbers if int(x) % 2 == 0) )  # int(x) !!!
# 6
```